# Xamarin Form Binding To Nested Class

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I want to bind my entry and my label to a class inside my view model, so whenever my entry changes, my label and my class inside view model also changes

here is my code

**Model**

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**View Model**

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Model = new MyModel();
    }

    private MyModel _Model;
    public MyModel Model
    {
        get { return _Model; }
        set
        {
            _Model = Model;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**BehindCode**

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new MyViewModel();
    }
}
```

**PAGE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="RKE.Page1">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding Model.Name}"/>
        <Entry Text="{Binding Model.Name}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I want to make the label, and my viewmodel change whenever the entry change. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement INotify for model also

```
public class MyModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _name;
    string _description;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Name 
    { 
        get => _name; 
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(); 
        } 
    }

    public string Description 
    { 
        get => _description;
        set
        {
            _Description = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged(); 
        }
    }

    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "") =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```